# Assigning different uri paths to different servers

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, path, uri

I have the following situation:

There is a domain with offers different services like a blog, a forum and a wiki whic are reachable via different URI paths all at e.g. IP 123.123.123.123:

www.example.com/blog
www.example.com/forum
... etc.

Now, e.g. the forum should be hosted by a different server from the one the domain itself relates to. In case the domain uses subdomains like , etc. are easy since I can assign a different IP to each subdomain. However how may this be achieved with different paths? Do I have to do some rewrite rules in the vhost of the apache webserver? Something else? An example will be cool.

Cheers and thank you for any hint or pointer

Comment: Search for "Apache reverse proxy", and study the guides available and then return back if you have any specific questions.

Comment: Since my comment will be too long I will add an answer though this is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointer. So a proxy is indeed the way to go. So from what I have read I have to do the following:

`1.` Create a subdomain at `example.com`, e.g. `blog.example.com`

`2.` Create the vhost on the remote server and do the redirect rules and other stuff so that content is emitted like `http://blog.example.com/blog`. The regular stuff as if no proxying is involved.

`3.` Add the following to the local server's vhost for `www.example.com` (mod_proxy_html version older than 3.1):

`ProxyRequests Off
SetOutputFilter proxy-html
ProxyHTMLExtended On
ProxyPass /blog/ http://blog.example.com/
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://blog.example.com /blog
<Location /blog/>
    ProxyPassReverse /
    ProxyHTMLURLMap / /blog/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap /blog /blog
    RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
</Location>`

`4.` Point `blog.example.com` to the remote server by adding its IP to the A-Record of the subdomain.

`5.` Done.